# Bald detection using image processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I was wondering if someone can provide me a guideline to detect if a person in a picture is bald or not, or even better, how much hair s\he has. 
So far I tried to detect the face and the eyes position. From that information, I roughly estimate the forehead and bald area by cutting the area above the eyes as high as some portion of the face.

Then I extract **HOG** features and train the system with bald and not-bald images using **SVM**.

Now when I'm looking at the test results, I see some pictures classified as bald but some of them actually have blonde hair or long forehead that hair is not visible after the cutting process. I'm using **MATLAB** for these operations.

So I know the method seems to be a bit naive, but can you suggest a way of finding out the bald area or extracting the hair, if exists. What method would be the most appropriate for that kind of problem?

Comment: You need to define the problem properly. We don't know anything about your data. Neither which data do you use for training and which for testing. Probably, if it is detecting blonde people as bold, is because you don't have any blonde in the training set.

Comment: Well, I have a bald dataset and a not-bald dataset. There must be blonde hairs in the not-bald dataset. I guess the classifier takes the yellow hair as skin, maybe this is the reason.

Answer (score 4):

very general,  so answer is general unless further info provided

1. Use Computer Vision (e.g [MATLAB Computer Vision toolkit](https://www.mathworks.com/products/computer-vision.html)) to detect face/head
2. head has analogies (for human faces), using these one can get the area of the head where hair or baldness is (it seems you already have these)
3. Calculate the (probabilistic color space model) range where the skin of the person lies (most peorple have similar skin collor space range)
4. Calculate percentage of skin versus other color (meaning hair) in that area
5. You have it!

To estimate a skin color model check following papers:

1. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.56.8637&rep=rep1&type=pdf
2. http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/135966
3. http://www.eurasip.org/Proceedings/Eusipco/Eusipco2010/Contents/papers/1569293757.pdf
4. [Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1300557)

If an area does not fit well with skin model it can be taken as non-skin (meaning hair, assuming no hats etc are present in samples)

Comment: I'm using Matlab for these operations

Comment: ok edited answer, if you need more i can update. NOTE that there are many methods, here, a color-space-model method is proposed, very fast and accurate in most cases, other approaches exist as well

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is, based on the image, sometimes the cut area above the eyes doesn't represent well the area I wanted, considering vast varieties of test images. For example, in most cases, it cuts the forehead of the face and classify it as bald while the image has hair.

Comment: yes, this is an issue with the sample images, an estimator cannot estimate sth that is not there to estimate! So the sample images would have to be of certain formar to be used correctly

Comment: Besides that, do you think one-class SVM classification with only bald images would work better rather than using binary SVM with bald and not-bald images? In that case, the system would recognize bald images and treat anything else as other.

Comment: well i dont use SVMs so much (or rather at all), but SVM are for detection and you need more you need percentage, so i would suggest this approach, maybe someone who is involved in SVM classification can offer another answer

Answer (score 1):

Head region is very small, hence, using HOG for classification doesn't make much sense.

You can use *prior information* - like detect faces; baldness/hair is certain to be found on the area above the face. Also, use some denser feature descriptors.

You are probably ending up with very sparse representation or equivalently less information because of which your classifier is not able to classify correctly.